# How to extract specific tables from html file using native powershell commands?

Tags: html, powershell, csv, powershell-cmdlet

I make use of the PAL tool (https://pal.codeplex.com/) to generate HTML reports from perfmon logs within Windows. After PAL processes .blg files from perfmon it dumps the information into an HTML document that contains tables with various data points about how the system performed. I am currently writing a script that looks at the contents of a directory for all HTML files, and does a get-content on all the HTML files.

What I would like to do is scrape the dump of this get-content blob for specific tables that have  varying amount of rows. Is it possible using native powershell cmdlets to look for specific tables, count how many rows are in each table, and dump *just* the desired tables and table rows?

Here is an example of the table format I'm trying to scrape:

```
<H3>Overall Counter Instance Statistics</H3>
<TABLE ID="table6" BORDER=1 CELLPADDING=2>
<TR><TH><B>Condition</B></TH><TH><B>\LogicalDisk(*)\Disk Transfers/sec</B></TH><TH><B>Min</B></TH><TH><B>Avg</B></TH><TH><B>Max</B></TH><TH><B>Hourly Trend</B></TH><TH><B>Std Deviation</B></TH><TH><B>10% of Outliers Removed</B></TH><TH><B>20% of Outliers Removed</B></TH><TH><B>30% of Outliers Removed</B></TH></TR>
<TR><TD>No Thresholds</TD><TD>MACHINENAME/C:</TD><TD>1</TD><TD>7</TD><TD>310</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>11</TD><TD>5</TD><TD>5</TD><TD>5</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>No Thresholds</TD><TD>MACHINENAME/D:</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>No Thresholds</TD><TD>MACHINENAME/E:</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>24</TD><TD>164</TD><TD>-1</TD><TD>11</TD><TD>22</TD><TD>21</TD><TD>20</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>No Thresholds</TD><TD>MACHINENAME/HarddiskVolume5</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>2</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>No Thresholds</TD><TD>MACHINENAME/L:</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>No Thresholds</TD><TD>MACHINENAME/T:</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>7</TD><TD>430</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>21</TD><TD>3</TD><TD>2</TD><TD>2</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
```

The Table ID is constant among all the output files, but the amount of table rows is not. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you need specific rows in the table, or the entire table?

Comment: I need the entire table. I don't just need one table either; I will be scraping several tables and aggregating the information in a CSV file for easy excel imports.

Comment: What do you consider "native command"? PS doesn't have any stock cmdlets that parse HTML _files_ but if you have IE installed you can do IE automation via `New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application`. Then you can get the table using [GetElementById .NET method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: You might be able to use regex to find the starting `<table id=` tag and then the ending `</table>` tag. Dump the result of the regex. Will all the tables you want dumped be use the same `ID="table6"` ?

Comment: @ Alexander: I consider a "native command" to be a command that is "out of the box" within powershell without having to import any third party modules. Ultimately this is a parsing exercise throughout a large blob of structured text, so I imagine that it will involve a method of locating the desired tables within the blob, a loop to count how many rows are in the table, a way to echo the filtered results. 

I will then be running a ConvertTo-CSV on the results.

Comment: @JGrice There are 4 tables that I want from the files. They all are prefixed with ID="table6" or "table9" etc.

Comment: Carter Shanklin made some code that you might be able to use to your advantage [here](http://poshcode.org/561)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, this isn't thoroughly tested but works with your example table in PS 2.0 with IE11:

```
# Parsing HTML with IE.
$oIE = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$oIE.Navigate("file.html")
$oHtmlDoc = $oIE.Document

# Getting table by ID.
$oTable = $oHtmlDoc.getElementByID("table6")

# Extracting table rows as a collection.
$oTbody = $oTable.childNodes | Where-Object { $_.tagName -eq "tbody" }
$cTrs = $oTbody.childNodes | Where-Object { $_.tagName -eq "tr" }

# Creating a collection of table headers.
$cThs = $cTrs[0].childNodes | Where-Object { $_.tagName -eq "th" }
$cHeaders = @()
foreach ($oTh in $cThs) {
    $cHeaders += `
        ($oTh.childNodes | Where-Object { $_.tagName -eq "b" }).innerHTML
}

# Converting rows to a collection of PS objects exportable to CSV.
$cCsv = @()
foreach ($oTr in $cTrs) {
    $cTds = $oTr.childNodes | Where-Object { $_.tagName -eq "td" }
    # Skipping the first row (headers).
    if ([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($cTds)) { continue }
    $oRow = New-Object PSObject
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $cHeaders.Count; $i++) {
        $oRow | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $cHeaders[$i] `
            -Value $cTds[$i].innerHTML
    }
    $cCsv += $oRow
}

# Closing IE.
$oIE.Quit()

# Exporting CSV.
$cCsv | Export-Csv -Path "file.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Honestly, I didn't aim for optimal code. It's just an example of how you could work with DOM objects in PS and convert them to PS objects.

Comment: Thanks! You have been a huge help! I just tested this out using one of my local HTML files and it parsed out the information in Table 6. I'll hack at your script and see if I can get it to output the contents of the other tables.

Answer (score 6):

I see you accepted an answer but I thought I'd add a RegEx solution in here too. No COM objects needed for this one, and should be PSv2 friendly I'm pretty sure.

```
$Path = 'C:\Path\To\File.html'
[regex]$regex = "(?s)<TABLE ID=.*?</TABLE>"
$tables = $regex.matches((GC C:\Temp\test.txt -raw)).groups.value
ForEach($String in $tables){
    $table = $string.split("`n")
    $CurTable = @()
    $CurTableName = ([regex]'TABLE ID="([^"]*)"').matches($table[0]).groups[1].value
    $CurTable += ($table[1] -replace "</B></TH><TH><B>",",") -replace "</?(TR|TH|B)>"
    $CurTable += $table[2..($table.count-2)]|ForEach{$_ -replace "</TD><TD>","," -replace "</?T(D|R)>"}
    $CurTable | convertfrom-csv | export-csv "C:\Path\To\Output\$CurTableName.csv" -notype
}
```

That should output a CSV file for each table found. Such as table6.csv, table9.csv etc. If you wanted to output CSVs per HTML file you could wrap the entire thing in a ForEach loop like:

```
ForEach($File in (Get-ChildItem "$Path\*.html")){
    Insert above code here
}
```

You would need to modify the `$tables =` line so that it was `GC $file.fullname` to that it would load up each file as it iterated through.

Then just modify the Export-Csv to something like:

```
$CurTable | convertfrom-csv | export-csv "C:\Path\To\Output\$($File.BaseName)\$CurTableName.csv" -notype
```

So if you had Server01.html with 3 tables in it you would get a folder named Server01 with 3 CSV files in it, one for each table.