# Possible to convert table to csv in powershell?

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to convert an HTML table to a powershell csv?

I dont think there is a native way to do this through powershell, if anyone else has done something similar and would like to share code I would appreciate it greatly.

An example of the table is here http://pastebin.com/8pb7J97x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract specific tables from html file using native powershell commands?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940510/how-to-extract-specific-tables-from-html-file-using-native-powershell-commands)

Comment: The paste bin example will always be a variable and will never become a file, not sure I can use the IE example

Comment: Variable, file, memory stream, cloud... it's all 'data' and can be parsed, dissected, and handled equally in the end.

Answer (score 0):

google gave me this, and it seems to work, but the result will likely need to be cleaned up because of the way your table is formatted

http://poshcode.org/561

```
Parse-HtmlTable -url 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14500910/tempfile.html' -tableNumber 2
```

Comment: I've stripped the table down to pretty basic tags: http://pastebin.com/shTnE3iC and I still cant get 'parse-htmltable' to run it. I get

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:9 char:1
+ $value = $value.trim()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull