# Extracting string from html web scrape

Tags: html, powershell, dom, web-scraping

I'm looking for some guidance on a web scraping script i'm working on.

All is going well but I'm stuck on stripping out the image file data.

I'm currently doing a WebRequest, getting elements by class, selecting outerHTML, but need to strip out just the contents of attribute `data-imagezoom` as per this example.

Sample data:

```html
<a class="aaImg" href="https://imagehost.ssl.server123.com/Product-800x800/image.jpg">
    <img class="aaTmb" alt="Matrix 900 x 900 test" src="https://imagehost.ssl.server123.com/Product-190x190/image.jpg" item="image"
         data-imagezoom="https://imagehost.ssl.server123.com/Product-1600x1600/image.jpg" data-thumbnail="https://imagehost.ssl.server123.com/Product-190x190/image.jpg">
    </img>
</a>
```

Current code to get that data:

```bsh
$ProductInfo = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $ProductURL
$ProductImageRaw = $ProductInfo.ParsedHTML.body.getElementsByClassName("aaImg") |
                   Select outerHTML
```

I can obviously get the first image by selecting the `href` attribute easily.

I was 'dirty coding' by replacing 800x800 with 1600x1600 as the filenames are the same, just a different path, but that came unstuck pretty quick when there were inconsistencies in path names.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the outer `<a>` element's `<img>` child element and call its **`.getAttribute()` method** to get the attribute value of interest:

```
$ProductInfo.ParsedHTML.body.getElementsByClassName("aaImg").
  childnodes[0].getAttribute('data-imagezoom')
```

- `.childnodes[0]` returns the first child node (element)
- `.getAttributes('data-imagezoom')` returns the value of the `data-imagezoom` attribute.<sup>[1]</sup>

This should return string `https://imagehost.ssl.server123.com/Product-1600x1600/image.jpg`.

---

As for [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55185374/45375):

**Using *regexes* (or substring search) to parse structured data such as HTML and XML is *brittle* and best avoided.**
For instance, if the source HTML changes to use `'...'` instead of `"..."` around attribute values, your solution breaks (this particular case is not hard to account for in a regex, but there are many more ways in which such parsing can go wrong).

---

**Cross-platform perspective**:

Regrettably, **the `.ParsedHTML` property with its HTML DOM is only available in *Windows PowerShell*** (and its COM implementation is cumbersome and slow to work with in PowerShell).

**PowerShell *Core***, even on Windows, doesn't support it, and there's **no in-box HTML parser available** (as of PowerShell Core 6.2.0).

The [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) NuGet package is a popular open-source HTML parser, but it is aimed at C# and therefore nontrivial to install and use in PowerShell.

That said, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52374548/how-do-you-get-table-data-from-a-website-after-you-login-using-powershell/52376988#52376988) by [TheIncorrigible1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8188846/theincorrigible1) has a working example that downloads the required assembly on demand.

---

<sup>[1] Note that `.getAttribute()` is necessary to access *custom* attributes, whereas *standard* attributes such as `id` and, in the case of `<a>` elements, `href`, are represented directly as *object properties* (e.g., `.id`; note that `.getAttribute()` works with standard attributes too.)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

So, after a quick crash course in some Regex, this is what I've come up with.

```
(?<=data-imagezoom=").*?(?="\s)
```

A positive lookbehind, select all until the closing quotes and whitespace.

Thanks all.