# Authentication With Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

The login page is this: https://login.procore.com/

I feel like I'm close to getting it to work, but have hit a brick wall due to a lack of understanding of login procedures. Here is the code so far, without the actual sign in information.

```
$r=Invoke-WebRequest https://login.procore.com/ -SessionVariable fb

$form = $r.Forms[0]

$form.Fields["session_email"] = "xxxxxxxxx"
$form.Fields["session_password"] = "xxxxxxxx"

$r=Invoke-WebRequest ('https://login.procore.com/' + $form.Action) -WebSession $fb -Method $form.Method  -Body $form.Fields
```

Could someone help me understand what is missing? I did notice that `$form.Fields` contains an empty field named: **session_sso_target_url**, but honestly have no clue what it means, or how to use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get table data from a website after you login using powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52374548/how-do-you-get-table-data-from-a-website-after-you-login-using-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

You've given me insufficient info to provide a complete answer, because I don't have a login and don't see a way to sign up for a free trial, and you haven't stated what kind of error you are getting.

I hazard a guess that `session_sso_target_url` relates to federation, which is semantically related to single sign-on (SSO). In federation, an application is configured to accept logins from another login domain. The obvious example in corporateland is ADFS, but any time you see an app that says *Login with Facebook* or *Login with Google*, that's the same thing. Federation is a big topic. The meaning of having a target URL is that the browser is often redirected to the identity provider (ADFS / FB / GOOG etc) with the callback URL that the browser should come back to once it is authenticated.

Suffice it to say that I suspect that you need do nothing with this field! And the reason I say this is because I hit it with Fiddler.

You should know about Fiddler. It is a cost-free debugging proxy from Telerik. I am not affiliated with Telerik, but I owe them hours of saved time when web scraping. (It is not the only tool for the job, and if any moderator deems that I am violating site rules, I will be happy to sanitise this post.)

Do this:

- install Fiddler
- Set it up to listen on 127:0.0.1:whatever and to be your system proxy
- in Tools > Options > HTTPS, set it to decrypt HTTPS (this will replace all certs with auto-generated self-signed ones, so do not leave this running while you perform other tasks)
- Set your filters to only include traffic to *.procore.com
- Log in through your browser - you should now see web traffic in the left-hand pane. This captured traffic is your baseline.
- Select any one web request and look at the Inspectors tab in the right-hand pane. You can look at Raw, Forms, Cookies, etc. This gives you a low-level view of what your client is doing.
- Run your code snippet. You can now compare the differences between the baseline and your code, and adjust accordingly.

Comment: I installed and ran Fiddler, and the session_sso_target_url is empty just like you said. The login process for Procore seems way too complicated for what I know how to do. Will have to abandon this project for now. Thank you for your answer, you got me a lot closer to my goal, but my lack of experience in this area is holding me back.